# Can anyone identify this chip which I think to be an optocoupler?

Tags: identification, optoelectronics

I'm trying to troubleshoot a Renishaw H-2000-5062-07-A optical receiver for a tool piece used in a milling machine.  It has several of these 8-SOIC(?) parts and I very much suspect that they are optoisolators with transistor outputs. The package is of a white plastic typical to many optoisolators and it is 5mm wide. What looks to be a manufacturer's mark is the letter Q with breaks in the ellipse at 2, 6 & 10 o'clock.
That's followed by the number 206 and below that is 045S.  I've had no luck finding a company that used that Q marking or those numbers.  Does anyone have any information on this part?  Thank you!

[image]

Comment: A slightly wider photo that shows the traces connecting to the part would be helpful in figuring out which parts are potentially matching candidates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Logo does not match, but perhaps a pin compatible version of Fairchild/ON MOC206 optocoupler with transistor output?

[image]

[Fairchild datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/MOC217M_D-2316188.pdf)

The logo resembles QP semiconductor, but I don’t find anything pointing to them making optocouplers.

[image]

Comment: Based on which pins seem to be used and unused on the device I'd say that you nailed it in one. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I think it's from QT Optoelectronics, which was acquired by Fairchild in 2000 Fairchild was then swallowed up by ON in 2016.

[image]

The part does not appear in QT's 1995/6 databook, which is available [online](https://usermanual.wiki/Document/1995QTOptoelectronicProductDataBook.1529942277/help), but's most likely MOC206-M as @winny suggests  (+1), and the ON part should be a match. Optoisolators do tend to age due to the LED losing brightness, especially if it is driven hard.

Comment: That would make perfect sense since the naming convention, date code and placement matches that of Fairchild too.